# Display confirmation message next to a single table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Trying to show "Product Added!" message to the right of the row where the user selected 'Add'. The way I have it right now is:

```
var addToCart = function (idFromButton) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { prodID: idFromButton },
                url: '@Url.Action("Add", "ShoppingCart")',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $('#BadgeIcon').html(data).fadeOut(1).fadeIn('fast');

                    $('.fakeLink-' + idFromButton).text("Product Added!").css("color", "green").fadeIn(600).fadeOut("slow");
                }
            });
        }
```

which changes the 'Add' button green and fades it away.

I have also tried creating a new row element to the right of the 'Add' column and adding the message there. It works, but moves the 'Add' button to the left during the fading animation, not to mention that it permanently removes the border of that last column upon click until page is refreshed.

Here is my table:

```
<table class="table" id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Product Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Image
            </th>
            <th>
                Add to Cart
            </th>
        </tr>

        @if (Model.Results.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.Results)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Price.ToString("$0.00")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (item.ImageFile != null)
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImageFile)" />
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="fakeLink" class="fakeLink-@item.ProductID" type="submit" value="Add" onclick="addToCart(@item.ProductID)" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">No product found.</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine except you need to update the button's `value`, not text. You may use the `val()` method.

```
$('.fakeLink-' + idFromButton).val("Product Added!")
                                       .css("color", "green").fadeIn(600).fadeOut("slow");
```

Also, i see you have duplicate id values for your button's inside the loop. Your id's should be unique. Actually you do not really need an Id for this case. You can simplify your code with unobutrusive javascript like this

```
 <td>
      <input class="addBtn" data-product="@item.ProductID" type="submit" value="Add"  />
 </td>
```

and listen to the click event of this type of button (button with addBtn css class) and you can use `$(this)` as the reference of clicked button.

```
$(function() {

        $(".addBtn").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _this = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { prodID: _this.data("product")  },
                    url: '@Url.Action("Add", "ShoppingCart")',
                    success: function (data) {
                    _this.val("Product Added!").css("color", "green").fadeIn(600)
                                                                    .fadeOut("slow");
                    }
            });

        });
});
```

**EDIT :** If you want to keep the Add button intact, but want to show a message next to that, you can do this.

```
success: function (data) {
         var msg = $("<span />").html("Product added").css("display","none");              
         msg.appendTo(_this.parent()).fadeIn(500).fadeOut("slow");
 }
```

You may apply additional css styles to the message span as needed.

Comment: I agree this is another way to do it, but it's more of the fact that the Add button is being faded away when I simply want a message next to the Add button that fades in and out temporarily while maintaining the integrity of the Add button

Comment: I see. See the updated answer which will handle that use case.

Comment: Shyju, I have tried your code with what you added under Edit and it doesn't work. Unless it only works with your first block of code and is not compatible with what I currently have

Comment: **it doesn't work** What exactly is not working ? Are you getting an error ?

Comment: I apoligize for no clarification: it does not display the message. It calls the controller as per usual, and updates the BadgeIcon, but does not display anything afterwards. No fade either

Comment: If you follow what i specified in the answer. It will work. See the working sample here http://jsbin.com/hubuxebevo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I have followed what you specified, and still no message shows up. Not only that, the other columns are getting pushed while the fade effect is happening. The BadgeIcon isn't even being updated

Comment: Update: Missed some parenthesis and now it works, but still pushes the other columns while fading effect is happening